# Where to store RavenDb indexes?

Tags: .net, nosql, ravendb

What is the best place in solution structure to store RavenDb indexes definitions? I have two executables: ASP.NET MVC Frontend and some background tasks executor. Both of them use only indexes which are specific to this project (so there is are no indexes which are used from both projects). So I see two options for storing indexes:

1. In one special project called RavenDbInfrastructure
2. Locally in both projects

The first option looks more reasonable for me but contrary indexes are usually view-specific so it looks logical to place them to the project where they will be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A separate project for the indexes would be best, if you have shared indexes.
If you have separate indexes for both, use them locally.